# communication cost of a key agreement protocol

Tags: cryptography, serial-communication, telecommunication

I have a key agreement protocol that runs between a node i and n other nodes in the CAN bus in parallel in order to establish a session key *SK* between i and each node j. The protocol is like this:[Protocol exchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73WUN.png).

the session key is established with two messages exchanges between the two nodes. each message is 325 bits. The CAN bus has also a load of 30 % .

My question is what tools I can use to model the situation in order to estimate the influence of the protocol execution on the bus load and the latency ?

Thanks in advance